# WooCommerce - Add $order_total to place order button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to add `$order->get_total();` to my woocommerce place order button, on the checkout page. So I just want it to display the total as an string.

This is what I have in my *functions.php*, which is returning a blank.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'woo_custom_order_button_text' ); 

function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( $order->get_total(), 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

I have tried this as well:

```
function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( $order_total, 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

Both snippets returns a blank, nothing.

How can this be done?
Thanks.

Comment: is it possible that $order_total is simply not defined? Shouldn't you pass it as a parameter to the function? or add a "global $order_total;" line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have to use `WC()` which is an alias of `global $woocommerce` to
>   access WooCommerce related data, and to access cart information you
>   have to use `WC()->cart`.

This code should work for you.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_button_text', 'woo_custom_order_button_text');

function woo_custom_order_button_text()
{
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->total;    
    return __('Your text ' . $cart_total, 'woocommerce');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't knew this, I have tested with `global $woocommerce;` the code was working, any way I'm updating my answer. and Thanks @LoicTheAztec, I always learn new stuff from you. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Raunak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41931465/9042245) set me on the right path - this code includes the currency symbol and total in the purchase button.

```
/**
 * Custom Purchase Button Text with Total on Checkout
 */
function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    $cart_total = wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price( WC()->cart->total ) );
    /* translators: Pay $cart_total total amount. */
    return sprintf( __( 'Pay %1$s', 'text-domain' ), $cart_total );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'woo_custom_order_button_text' );
```